# Where is the Associated / Related model loading happens

Tags: php, model-view-controller

I'm writing a MVC application in PHP from the scratch for an assignment. Where does the associated / related models are normally loaded.

I wrote the front controller, models and views and they are working. Now I need to load the associated models. I have defined the associations in the model. Now I need to place my associated model loading code somewhere in my application.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Not sure i understand your question, could you clarify

Comment: I have added the explanation. Appreciate any help.

Comment: All domain objects are loaded at the database layer (DAO or DataMapper or ...whatever). Is that your question?

Comment: For more information about MVC refer to this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5863870/how-should-a-model-be-structured-in-mvc/5864000#5864000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where models are loaded depends on the complexity of your application/storage

1. In a simple MVC framework you can load the model with info from a storage source from the controller yourself
2. In a more advanced framework you can use a Service Layer to keep your code DRY and make it easier for yourself
3. In all the big frameworks you most of the time have some sort of abstraction layer between the storage and your service layer

Comment: Thanks, Based on your answer, I checked the cakePHP and found that, it has a abstraction layer which handles all these complex things. Thanks for turning the lights on.

Comment: @KasunRajapaksha you really should **not** use CakePHP as example for proper application/framework design.

Comment: Really, why? I found that it's structure differs to the MVC definition. Is there any other serious issues. If so what framework you suggest?